# Using JS variable inside $.ajax function - null?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I've seen lots of similar questions but I *can't* find an answer! I am trying to open a PHP file, passing some Javascript variables into the URL, using $.ajax. But, when I define the variable in Javascript then try to use it inside $.ajax, it returns null and the variable is not defined. How can I pass this variable?

Thanks in advance!
-C

```
var searchTerm = "startups";
function Initialize() {
  PopulateTable(searchTerm);
 }
function PopulateTable(searchTerm) {
    $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data:   "tableName=Events&searchTerm=" + searchTerm, 
            // It's not recognizing my JS variables inside Ajax. Has it always been this way?           
            url: "/php/postData.php",  
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Doing AJAX and immediately reloading the page seems like you might be shooting yourself in the foot.  I would speculate that the reload is causing "funny" behaviour with that ajax request.  Better to avoid that reload altogether.  Maybe put it into your "success" function if the alternative means massive rewriting.  Fix that and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this, even if your use of globals and parameters is a bit confusing. Is it possible `var searchTerm` is not defined in a global scope? Assuming you are calling "initialize" AFTER the global variable "searchTerm" is defined, it should work.

Comment: make sure `searchTerm` contains something...

Comment: .. although i missed this crucial bit before, calling `window.location.reload()` immediately after executing an ajax call is going to result in nothing at all happening (except for the page reloading).

Comment: Is searchTerm even set when PopulateTable is called? try doing `alert(searchTerm)` right before the `$.ajax()` to see what's been passed in to the function.

Comment: Doh! The problem was      window.loaction.reload(). Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 7):

`$.ajax({ ...` will spawn an asynchronous request to your php resource.  `window.location.reload();` will reload your page before that request is received and anything can be done with it.  If you need to reload the page, do it inside here:

```
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
            alert(data);
            window.location.reload();
        }
```

Comment: Doh! The problem was staring me right in the face and I wasn't looking. This worked perfectly after moving window.location.reload(). Thank you!

Comment: Hey Charles, if this solved your problem you should mark it as accepted.  That way I get points and it helps others :)